# Error while compiling simple code in boost. How to find the name of the library?

Tags: boost, g++

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/allocation/server.cpp

```
   g++ -L./lib/boost_1_41_0/ -L./lib/soci-3.0.0/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L./ -I/usr/include -I./lib/boost_1_41_0 -o main server.o -lssl -pthread
    server.o: In function `error_code':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o: In function `get_system_category':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o: In function `error_code':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:209: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o: In function `error_code':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o: In function `get_system_category':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o: In function `error_code':
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    /test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
    server.o:/test/mycode/./lib/boost_1_41_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:218: more undefined references to `boost::system::get_system_category()' follow
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [main] Error 1
```

How to remove the above error

Answer (score 1):

You want `-lboost_system`.

The Boost build system builds multiple variants of a single library.  For example, a thread safe version of that library is `-lboost_system-mt`.  To understand how the variants are named, see the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming).

Comment: g++ -L./lib/boost_1_41_0/ -L./lib/soci-3.0.0/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L./ -I/usr/include -I./lib/boost_1_41_0 -o main server.o -lssl -lboost_system-mt -pthread
/usr/bin/ld.real: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: So what libraries do you have in lib/boost_1_41_0

Comment: I have boost_system (both as a .a and as a .so) and boost_system-mt.